# SecurityContextHolderStrategy (MODE_THREADLOCAL) switches users during big load on server

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to solve a problem with security in our application, that user is relogged on another's account and is seeing someone else's data. The application has been running successfully on the production for few years now and the problem happens very rarely, only during very big load on the server.
I suppose that it may be caused by SecurityContextHolderStrategy(*MODE_THREADLOCAL*). 
1)
Is it possible that the class is not thread-safe during very big load on server?

2) Have anybody ever heard about such problem in spring-security 3.1.3.RELASE?

**Background:**
We use async dispatcher servlet and the requests are handled by threads from the pool.
In the dispatcher servlet we get securityContext by calling *SecurityContextHolder.getContextHolderStrategy().getContext()* and then pass it to the method *processAsyncRequest*(...).
ProcessAsyncRequest is handled by another thread, so we call *SecurityContextHolder.getContextHolderStrategy().setContext(securityContext)*.
I suppose that the reason is that getContext() method returned another user's context and then it was saved with setContext(), so wrong context was stored permanently...

**Log analysis:**
UserA authenticated and was surfing on the page. Few minutes later userB authenticated. Every request with userA's ip after userB's authentication, was logged with userB's id...

Comment: First of all you shouldn't be messing around with setting the security context yourself, second you also have to make the filters async supported and afaik async support was added in Spring Security 3.2 and not 3.1...

Comment: you can try http://vmlens.com. It is developed to find race conditions.